# Обрезка части строки с условиями

Tags: php

Здраствуйте нужна помощь, есть задача обрезать начало текста где есть `№` но при этом еще проверять длину строки, есть:

```
$str1 = '№18 в Зарубежная классика';
$str2 = '№7 в Литература 20 века';
```

нужно проверять на наличие `№` и удалить все до заглавной что бы в результате получилось так:

```
$str1 = 'Зарубежная классика';
$str2 = 'Литература 20 века';
```

Как можно проверить и обрезать все это дело?

*П.С. Только начинаю прогить))*

Comment: почитайте про регулярные выражения, `preg_replace()`

Comment: Прочитать про [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) можно в официальной документации php.net. О синтаксисе регулярных выражений тут https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php. Попробовать регулярки в деле удобно на сайте https://regex101.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода

```
$str1 = '№18 в Зарубежная классика';
preg_match("/№.*([А-Я].*)/u", $str1,$key);
print_r($key[1]);
```

preq_match возвращает часть строки соответствующую шаблону.

/u добавляет поддержку Unicode

Регулярное выражение `"/№.*([А-Я].*)/u"`

Символ № далее любое количество символов ([А-Я].*) искомая группа, начинается с заглавной русской буквы.

Comment: Достаточно и [`preg_replace('~№[^\p{Lu}]+~u', '', $str)`](https://regex101.com/r/O8hNiR/1)

Comment: @Эдуард тоже вариант